# Confused on this assignment, any guidance?

Tags: sql, database, oracle, plsql, logic

The Problem:

First create a table called amttopay that has three fields: rec_no, idno and amt (make amount a numeric field that can hold 3 decimal places. You are also going to use a copy of the donor table for this assignment. Take in a number that matches an idno on the donor table. Check the yrgoal for that record. If it is larger than 500 then double it to create a new goal and write four records on the amttopay table containing the quarterly payment number (1 through 4), the idno, and the quarterly amount to pay to achieve the new goal. If it is not larger than 500 then add 50% to the goal to make the new goal and process it by writing the four records with the same information.

I've created the table, and I understand I've gotta write PL/SQL code to accomplish this, but what I'm not understanding is how the question is worded.

"If it is larger than 500 then double it to **create a new goal and write four records on the amttopay table containing the quarterly payment number (1 through 4), the idno, and the quarterly amount to pay to achieve the new goal**."

What does that mean? How would I go about bringing logic into this?

Thanks so much for the help.

Comment: Is rec_no the column in which you will record the payment number (1 to 4)? Also, why do you need to write PL/SQL code - what's wrong with plain SQL, which can solve this easily? And - is your teacher (or textbook) really using the terms "record" and "field" in regard to a table in a relational database, such as Oracle? You may want to ask for your money back, that shows sloppiness if not ignorance and should not be tolerated from someone who claims to be teaching this stuff to others.

Comment: @mathguy Perhaps you would be kind enough to point OP to a discussion on the differences between “rows” & “records” and “columns” & “fields”?

Comment: `mathguy`, `records` and `fields` is correct terminology.  Records do not exist as "rows" within a database nor the fields as "columns" within them.  They're just stored in physically varying places with some algorithm employed to track where they are stored and how each piece of information is related to the rest.  It is just convenient to abstactedly refer to them as existing in a tabular (or spreadsheet) form, which tends to result in records being referred to by the alias rows and fields by the alias columns.

Comment: @toonice, _"First create a table called amttopay that has three fields"_ is clearly wrong. I have less of a problem with _"Check the yrgoal for that record"_ although I do think "row" would have been clearer.

Comment: How is this clearly wrong?  Having an amount field (`amt`) seems valid and if this amount is also the central theme of the table then naming the table `amttopay` is fair.  A field to hold a foreign key that associates that amount with its owning entity (`idno`) is both fair and sensible.  And having a field that will uniquely identify each record (`rec_no`) is not just fair, but in many circumstances it will be required.

Comment: This is all off-topic, but from [the Oracle concepts manual](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/CNCPT/tablecls.htm): "A row is a collection of column information corresponding to a record in a table"  and "A field is the intersection of a row and column". At table level a field is *not* the same as a column, so it should be "a table called amttopay that has three columns", nor "fields". The rest is less clear-cut, particularly as some of the phrasing implies this is a PL/SQL-based exercise.

Comment: @mathguy , yes this is from my professor. The problem requires PL/SQL code looping to get credit. I've been confused on the way things have been worded since day one. Really hating this language, but I'm sure it has just been my experience. This is why I look to people like you to guide me the correct way, which I'm absolutely grateful for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you are trying to actually understand the question, this is how you would do it:

Break your statement into parts:

- Check the yrgoal for that record.
- If it is larger than 500 then

  - double it to create a new goal
  - and write four records on the amttopay table containing the quarterly payment number (1 through 4), the idno, and the quarterly amount to pay to achieve the new goal.
- If it is not larger than 500 then

  - add 50% to the goal to make the new goal
  - and process it by writing the four records with the same information.

Simplified, this gives the following:

- Create new record
- if `yrgoal`>500 then

  - double `yrgoal`
  - Create 4 records with `idno`and the quarterly amount
- else

  - `yrgoal` * 1.5
  - Create 4 records as before

The rest is up to you, of course …

Comment: Thank you so much Manngo, my main area of confusion comes from the "Create 4 records idno and the quarterly amount" What does this mean broken down? I'm sorry if I'm seeming very dumb.

Comment: I’m not entirely sure myself. My guess is that `amttopay` is a related table, and that each record would have the `idno` from the main table, and the quarterly amount, which is presumably the new `yrgoal`/4